# Given the real number $t = - \frac 5 4 \pi$, give the values of the sine, cosine and tangent.

Tags: trigonometry

I've found that these problems are quite hard for me, such as this: given the real number $t = - \frac 5 4 \pi$, give the values of the sine, cosine and tangent.

Is there any good explanation on HOW to do this?

THANK YOU!

Comment: Since sine, cosine and tangent have the same values on each interval of length $2\pi$, finding these at $-5\pi/4$ is the same as at $-5\pi/4+2\pi = 3\pi/4$. Can you do this now?

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, the proper pronounciation of the symbol $\pi$ isn't ***pi***. 
It's ***half-revolution***.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin 3\pi/4=\sin(\pi - \pi/4)= \text{ using identity } \cos(\pi - \theta)=-\cos \theta \text{ you will get }= -\cos \pi/4 =-\sqrt{2}/2$

You do similar for $\sin$ and $\tan$

Answer (score 0):

So using the very helpful comment, I realized that theta is 135 degrees, making it easy to find the sin, cos and tan of theta :)
\begin{align*}
\sin(135^\circ) & = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
\cos(135^\circ) & = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
\tan(135^\circ) & = -1
\end{align*}

Comment: You should show your results here so that your answer is complete.

Comment: Your answer is correct.  Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: If you are the person who posed the question, you should [merge](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your two accounts.  If you did not pose the question, you should explain how you arrived at your answer, which would be a good idea in any case.